# Does long tooltips affect webpage performance

Tags: html, css, performance, dom

In my web page there is a table with 1000 rows per page(pagination). I need to have a tool-tip (about 500 characters) for each row. Im using span, title attribute for the tool-tips.

Does long tool-tips affect the DOM performance ?

Comment: Tooltips that long are impractical to use

Comment: @Quentin first of all wonderful name. Second a huge amount of DOM elements always has an impact on the perfromance.

Comment: The more elements in DOM, the more a browser will spend time loading it.

Comment: I'd echo Quentin's usability concerns, but add that there are plenty of better ways to accomplish this. Because you haven't provided any code, all we can do is guess as to what your use case is. In the past, I've manually truncated `title` tooltip text to around 25 characters and added ellipses, then made it so clicking the row (or a button at the end of the row) launched a modal with the extended information for all cells of the row at once. You're the only person in a position to decide whether this will work for your situation.

Comment: I have use the tooltip as <span title="tooltipText"></span>

Comment: Im asking this question because it will not create new html elements in the DOM. @IronFlare

Comment: @QuentinAlbert no of elements will not increase because Im just adding title attribute the the existing <span> elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long OS-native tooltips *shouldn't* impact DOM performance because they're part of the browser application, not the page's rendering pipeline. They could potentially impact OS performance, but this is highly unlikely on all but the oldest machines.

With that being said, relying on `title` is **unwise** and **not a viable strategy** for the modern web. There are many reasons for this, but here are a few important ones:

1. The amount of time it's going to take for a user to *read*
   a 500-character tooltip will vastly outweigh the amount of time it
   would take to create a DOM element. If you're concerned about making a large 
   number of tooltips, just create *one element* that changes its absolute position and 
   content as needed. There are [JavaScript libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=tooltip+library+javascript) that will do this for you.
2. Tooltip behavior varies. Some browsers display the tooltip all on one
   line. Others resize the tooltip based on how close it is to the edge
   of the screen. All browsers put limits on the length of the tooltip 
   text, but this isn't standardized and can vary.
3. Lastly, and most damning, `title` tooltips **don't appear at all**
   on mobile devices, some screen readers, and for people who navigate
   with the keyboard because they can't use a mouse. There's nearly universal consensus<sup>[1][2][3]</sup> that the title attribute is harmful to accessibility.

Long story short, the minuscule performance benefit you might gain from using desktop browsers' native tooltip functionality is effectively cancelled out by the myriad issues with usability, consistency, and accessibility this approach will cause you in the long run.

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> [The A11Y Project - How-to: Use title attributes](https://a11yproject.com/posts/title-attributes/)</sup>

<sup><sup>[2]</sup> [David Ball - I thought title text improved accessibility. I was wrong.](https://silktide.com/blog/2013/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong)</sup>

<sup><sup>[3]</sup> [Yoast - Why you shouldn’t rely on the title attribute](https://developer.yoast.com/dont-rely-title-attribute/)</sup>

Comment: thanks for understanding my question. If it is not affect the rendering performance it will help me. As Im using this for one of my internal software, it doesn't use with mobile browsers. @IronFlare